# thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x14)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create the capability of deleting rows from a tableview and this is how I did it. The error is coming from the

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.homeworkArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Don't call `reloadData` in addition to calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `arrayWithObjects:` method requires a `nil` to terminate the list, so you need to say -

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

or even easier, use `arrayWithObject:`

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Or as @rmaddy points out, use array literal syntax -

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Also, you don't need the `reloadData` call - `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` will take care of updating the relevant rows in the table view.

Comment: Even easier is: `...deleteRowsAtIndexPath:@[indexPath] with...`

Answer (score 1):

It might be Help full for you I know it Same As Another Answer But it is my Own answer :-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle   forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        {
            [arrStations removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
```