# Deleting last row of a section causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have surfed around `Stackoverflow` and found similar questions but I still can't figure it out as it seems that I am doing it correctly.

So I have a table view of custom cells. Whenever I try to delete the last row in a given section, the app crashes and gives me the following error message:

> The number of sections contained in the table view after the update
>   (1) must 
>       be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the 
>       update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).

Here is my code:

```
// shifts = [[Shift]] (Shift is my class)
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return shifts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return shifts[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // Removing the element from my list
        shifts[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)

        // Removing empty lists if there are any
        var indexes = [Int]()
        for i in 0..<shifts.count {
            if shifts[i].count == 0 {
                indexes.append(i)
            }
        }
        var count = 0
        for number in indexes {
            shifts.remove(at: number-count)
            count += 1
        }

        // Deleting the row in the tableView
        myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)

    }
```

The other posts had the issue in their `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSections` methods, but my methods return the count of the list, and since I delete the element from the list before I delete the row, I can't figure out the problem.

**EDIT** Added code by Lion's advice still throwing error.

```
if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) > 1 {
            myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
        } else {
            let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
            indexSet.add(indexPath.section - 1)
            myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
            myTableView.deleteSections(indexSet as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
        }
```

**EDIT 2: SOLUTION** Above code was at fault, hence throwing an error.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if editingStyle == .delete {

    // Removing the element from my list
    shifts[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)

    // Removing empty lists if there are any
    var indexes = [Int]()
    for i in 0..<shifts.count {
        if shifts[i].count == 0 {
            indexes.append(i)
        }
    }
    var count = 0
    for number in indexes {
        shifts.remove(at: number-count)
        count += 1
    }

    // Deleting the row in the tableView
    if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) > 1 {
        myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
    } else {
        let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
        indexSet.add(indexPath.section) // This line was wrong in above code.
        myTableView.deleteSections(indexSet as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
    }

}
```

Comment: `myTableView.deleteSections([indexPath.section], with: .bottom)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once try by `reloading tableview` instead of deleting row, I mean `myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)`
 in  commit editingStyle method!

**Update :**

It is because if your section have no element then you are deleting section from your datasource I mean array! So, at that time you have to delete section also like

```
 myTableView.deleteSections(<#T##sections: IndexSet##IndexSet#>, with: <#T##UITableViewRowAnimation#>)
```

When you delete row  if it is not last then you can use `deleteRow` but if you want to delete last row then you have to delete section and do not delete row at this time!

OR relaod whole table as I have mentioned earlier!

Comment: That is how I have deleted rows so far, by calling `tableView.reloadData()`, However this has no animation.

Comment: Check my edit on post to see the code I added, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: when you are deleting section no need to delete the row. once try by deleting section only when row is last @BartekSpitza !

Comment: Ok, well I tried it and now its throwing `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1` :( Any ideas?

Comment: Try `let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)`

Comment: make sure that you are deleting same data from array which section you are deleting! put breakpoint and debug you will get idea! reffer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328537/exc-bad-access-when-im-trying-to-delete-a-uitableview-sections) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923109/thread-1exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x14)

Comment: Nevermind Lion. I got it to work! Obviously `indexSet.add(indexPath.section - 1)` was at fault. Don't know why I put the `- 1` there.

Comment: You can also just use an array of `Int` as the `IndexSet`.  Pass `[indexPath.section]` for the `IndexSet`.

Comment: @BartekSpitza : Yeah! :)

Comment: @vacawama Yes you are correct. 2 Lines of code less :)